# Change `innerHTML` of element using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

OK, I'm new at JavaScript, but I'm trying to change the `innerHTML` of a `div` element.
Here is my script that is not working:

```html
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function var1() {
document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = 'hi';
}
window.onLoad = var1();
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="test">change</div>
</body>
```

It should work, but for some reason it does not, any help?

Comment: The phrase "not working" covers an awful lot of scenarios.  What exactly is the error?

Comment: theres no error, its just not changing the text inside the 'test' div. i just tried and if i put the javascript under the div, it works. is there a way to make it work when above the div as i have shown?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Rather than assigning `var1` to `window.onload`, you're currently calling the function and storing its result. Also, this might be obvious, but `var1` seems like an odd name for a function. Try this:

```
function var1() {
  document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = 'hi';
}

window.onload = var1;
```

Note the casing of `onload`, as well as the missing parentheses after `var1`.

Comment: you should not use innerHTML it is non-standard and a bad practice. It’s a lot safer to use DOM methods like createElement, createTextNode and appendChild.

Comment: make sure it is "HTML" is capitalized

Answer (score 6):

Correct is:

```
window.onload = var1;
```

In your example value of `window.onload` is `undefined`, because function call `var1()` returns nothing (`undefined`).
Instead you should set the `onload` property to function (pointer) `var1`.

Comment: @David: Notice also the change from onLoad to onload. I tried it and it works just fine.

Answer (score 5):

Using `.innerHTML` is [non-standard,](http://domscripting.com/blog/display/35) and a terrible practice for many reasons.  You should create a new element using the proper standard methods and and add it to the tree where you want it.

Comment: No.  Using `innerHTML` is the fastest way.

Comment: doesn't mean is isn't bad practice

Comment: It's non standard, therefore it can lead to undefined behaviour, ie: security flaws, thus is bad practice. I can't believe someone voted this down...

Comment: Just to add some context to the "fastest" comment by Josh S. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18393981/append-vs-html-vs-innerhtml-performance

Answer (score 3):

Below is another simpler version

```html
<body>
 <div id="test">change</div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = 'hi';
 </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're getting an element with an id of "test", but there is no element with that id in your html.  There is, however, one called "text".

Comment: oh sorry, i fixed that i didnt copy and paste from my text just typed it in here, my bad. but yeh still doesnt work

Comment: Actually this "answer" should have been a comment as it does not fix the problem(s).

Answer (score 1):

Your example will work if you change the uppercase "L" to a lowercase "L" in "onLoad" and remove the parenthesis after `var1` where you currently have `window.onLoad = var1();`

Comment: While correct, an answer should also include some explanation (as e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/2254829/6607497 does).

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `onLoad` to `onload` and remove the parentheses `()` after `var1`:

```js
function var1() {
  document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = 'hi';
}
window.onload = var1; // onload
```

Comment: It’s a lot safer to use DOM methods like createElement, createTextNode and appendChild.

Comment: You can check that this will not solve the problem. You execute the function before the onload, which is unintended.

Comment: @brunoais updated. the issue I was trying to draw attention to there was the camelCase on onload.