# Jquery .html without deleting element content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Good Day Guys.

my scenario is I want to add a new element which is `ul li` on a certain tab which correspond to their own id. the code is working fine.. however I find that .append is much slower than .html... you see in my code if I change the `.append` to `.html` it will just display the last loop... since `.html` delete the existing elements inside and replace a new one...

what I want is to display them via `.html` with regards to their id.

**OBJECTS**

```
groups = [{
    GroupID: 1,
    tabPaneID: "home"
  },

  {
    GroupID: 2,
    tabPaneID: "edit"
  },

  {
    GroupID: 3,
    tabPaneID: "view"
  },

  {
    GroupID: 4,
    tabPaneID: "home"
  },

  {
    GroupID: 5,
    tabPaneID: "home"
  }
];

items = [{
  GroupID: 1,
  Item: "SampleItem1",
  Qty: 21
}, {
  GroupID: 1,
  Item: "SampleItem2",
  Qty: 21
}, {
  GroupID: 2,
  Item: "SampleItem3",
  Qty: 22
}, {
  GroupID: 3,
  Item: "SampleItem4",
  Qty: 23
}, {
  GroupID: 4,
  Item: "SampleItem5",
  Qty: 24
}, {
  GroupID: 4,
  Item: "SampleItem6",
  Qty: 25
}, {
  GroupID: 5,
  Item: "SampleItem7",
  Qty: 25
}];
```

**JQUERY**

```
$.each(settings.tabs, function (i, t) {
  $.each(settings.group, function (ObjID, groupObj) {
    if (t.tabPaneID == groupObj.tabPaneID) {
      $tabPane.find("#" + t.tabPaneID).append("<ul class='delta-ui-common-ul' id=group-" + groupObj.GroupID + "></ul>");

      $.each(settings.item, function (itemID, itemObj) {
        if (groupObj.GroupID == itemObj.GroupID) {
          var list = $tabPane.find("#" + t.tabPaneID);
          list.find("#group-" + groupObj.GroupID).append("<li>" + itemObj.Item + "</li>");

        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: @Tushar what is the difference? is it faster than append or .html?

Comment: Create a string of HTML markup in the loop, and then use `html` after loop to update

Comment: @Tushar so how will I know which element I will put the htmlstring? since it has regards to id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because html() replaces you have to do the appending yourself, something like:

```
var current_html = list.find("#group-"+groupObj.GroupID).html();
list.find("#group-"+groupObj.GroupID).html(current_html+"<li>"+itemObj.Item+"</li>");
```

jQuery.append() does more than just adding text to an element so jQuery.html() is quite a bit faster.

Answer (score 0):

Use `innerHTML`. It is faster than `append` and `html`.
like below

```html
<span id='foo'>I am </span>
<script>
  document.getElementById('foo').innerHTML += '<b>HTML</b>'
</script>
```

> [.append VS .html VS .innerHTML performance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18394084/3465753)

Comment: doesn't work though.. I don't know why.. I've also tried this method.

Comment: can you provide a fiddle , i'll try to play around .

Comment: NO. you can't use it with jquery selector

Comment: do it like this `document.getElementById("#group-"+groupObj.GroupID).innerHTML+="<li>"+itemObj.Item+"</li>"`